# what is the best way to add and delete columns in a TableViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

Good afternoon, I have a problem and hope you can advise me. First of all I apologize if something like this has already been asked, I think not, but still, forgive rookie mistakes

The project I'm doing is a TabBarViewController with two controllers. 
One that basically is able to capture a bar code and make a call to a Web service with the bar code to get me the item from the server. That item then want to show on the other controller.

My problem is i don't know how to pass the retrieved item to my custom UITableViewController, or which is the best way to achieve this.

This is the interface able to capture a bar code and connect to a web service

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
#import "ListaItemsViewController.h"


@interface ViewController : UIViewController < ZBarReaderDelegate,NSXMLParserDelegate >
{
    IBOutlet UILabel                  * resultText;
    ListaItemsViewController          * listaItemsViewController;

    MBProgressHUD                     * HUD;
    NSMutableData                     * xmlData;
   //neccesary to parse the possible error
   NSMutableString                   * faultString;
   BOOL                                esperandoFaultString;
   //neccesary to parse message from logIn and logOut methods webservice
   BOOL                                esperandoReturn;
   NSMutableString                   * returnString;
   //neccesary to parse and save an item
  BOOL                                esperandoItem;
  BOOL                                esperandoDescripcionItem;
  BOOL                                esperandoPrecioItem;
  BOOL                                esperandoNumTotalItem;
  NSMutableString                   * descripcionItem;
  NSMutableString                   * precioItem;
  NSMutableString                   * numeroTotalItem;

  NSXMLParser                       * parser;

}

@property (nonatomic,strong) MBProgressHUD            * HUD;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel      * resultText;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableData           * xmlData;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableString         * faultString;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableString         * returnString;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableString         * descripcionItem;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableString         * precioItem;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableString         * numeroTotalItem;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSXMLParser             * parser;
@property(nonatomic,strong) ListaItemsViewController          * listaItemsViewController;
- (IBAction) scanButtonTapped;

- (IBAction)esconderTeclado:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)mostrarTeclado:(id)sender;

@end
```

and this is the interface

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface ListaItemsViewController : UITableViewController
 {
      // the item list
      NSMutableArray * listaItems;
 }

 @property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray * listaItems;
 @end
```

this is the implementation file:

```
  #import "ListaItemsViewController.h"
  #import "CaracteristicasItemViewController.h"

  @implementation ListaItemsViewController

  @synthesize listaItems;

  - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
  {
     NSLog(@"ListaItemsViewController. initWithStyle...");
     self = [super initWithStyle:style];
     if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
     }
     return self;
  }

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
  {
     // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
  }

  #pragma mark - View lifecycle

  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      NSLog(@"ListaItemsViewController. viewDidLoad...");
     **//how do i create this item list with the items passed via web service?**
     listaItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"item1",@"item2",@"item3", nil];
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem; 
  }

  - (void)viewDidUnload
  {
      [super viewDidUnload];
  }

  - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {
      [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  }

  - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  } 

  - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
  {
     [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  }

  - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
  {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
  }

  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
  {
       // Return YES for supported orientations
       return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
  }

  #pragma mark - Table view data source

  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {
      return 1;
  }

  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        NSLog(@"[listaItems count]: %d",[listaItems count]);
       return [listaItems count];
  }

  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"celda";

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [listaItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [listaItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSLog(@"cell: %@",cell.textLabel.text);
    return cell;
  }


  // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
  - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
       // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
       return YES;
  }



  // Override to support editing the table view.
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:   (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
   **when i try to delete some row, the app crash, check!!**
       NSLog(@"commitEditingStyle...");
       [tableView beginUpdates];
       if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
       {
         // Delete the row from the data source
          [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
          //[listaItems delete:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];
       }   
       [tableView endUpdates];
       NSLog(@"end commitEditingStyle...");

    }




     #pragma mark - Table view delegate

     - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
      // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

      NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath.row: %d",indexPath.row);

             CaracteristicasItemViewController *caracteristicas =   [[CaracteristicasItemViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"CaracteristicasItemViewController" bundle:Nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:caracteristicas animated:YES];

      }

@end
```

Whats the best way to achieve this, the best practice?

Again, sorry if this is too easy for you guys, but I just started with this technology.
Regards

Comment: The title of the question and your actual question are not the same?  Which is correct?

Comment: Thx for the response and my apologies for the inconvenience.My problem is i don't know how to pass the retrieved item to my custom UITableViewController, or which is the best way to achieve this. The ítem is retrieved using first controller and i d like to add the ítem on the Custom tableview.

Comment: I put down what I thought was your question.  But now I am not sure if you are passing one item at a time back or an array of items?

Comment: now i realize that i need to pass one item at a time. I have tried this way:

Comment: - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
   if ([elementName isEqual:@"item"]){

Comment: //here i ll have to process the created item to put it on the shopping list. Do i need to create an entity?  NSMutableArray * lista = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"itemcito1", nil];
        if (!listaItemsViewController)
            listaItemsViewController = [[ListaItemsViewController alloc] init];
        listaItemsViewController.listaItems = lista;  
        //ahora muestro este mensaje proveniente del backend
        NSLog(@"added items to listaItems...")

Comment: sorry for the poor indentation

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the row without animation you could just delete the entry from the data source array `listaItems` and do a `-reloadData` on the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at the UITableView method:

```
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: (NSIndexPath) indexPath withRowAnimation: (UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather and with the given information from your ViewController.h file, your ViewController has an instant of ListaItemsViewController called listaItemsViewController.  And there is an iVar called listaItems in the ListaItemsViewController, so you can assign the retrieved items to listaItems like this (after you have instantiated the listaItemsViewController instant:

```
listaItemsViewController.listaItems = retrieveItems;  // or self.retrieveItems where retrievedItems is the array of items that you have retrieved from the web server.
```

Unfortunately, I could not figure out which of the variables you used for it.

Comment: Hi again, thx for the response!. You figured out almost everything. My ViewController has an instant to ListaItemsViewController called listaItemsViewController, inside it theres a NSMutableArray called listaItems. This is what i m trying to do:

Comment: I ve tried your way and it does not works. Sorry for the inconvenience ./**NSMutableArray * lista = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"itemcito1",@"itemcito2", nil];
    if (!listaItemsViewController)
        listaItemsViewController = [[ListaItemsViewController alloc] init];
    listaItemsViewController.listaItems = lista;  
    //ahora muestro este mensaje proveniente del backend
    NSLog(@"added items to listaItems..."); **/

Comment: this is ListaItemsViewController.viewDidLoad method:  

/**- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"ListaItemsViewController. viewDidLoad...");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
} **/

Comment: and this is ListaItemsViewController.numberOfRowsInSection method: /**  
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"[listaItems count]: %d",[listaItems count]);
    return [listaItems count];
} **/

The messages from log are "added items to listaItems..." next to ListaItemsViewController. viewDidLoad... and finally [listaItems count]: 0 How is it possible, what do am doing wrong?

Comment: sorry for the poor indentation

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I have a very clear picture of what you have.  The only thing I can suggest (if I am right by guessing), is that you can use listaItemsViewController.listaItems to keep the list up to date.  You need to do it from your ViewController (since you have an instant of ListaItemsViewController) and in ListaItemsViewController.  In ListaItemsViewController, when item is being added or deleted from tableview, you need to update the listaItems array.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hello again, i already solved my problem. I have used entities stored in context. Now i have another problems but that s for another day. Thx everyone who participate on this thread.